# Is there any way to bypass the Maps JS deferred loading of map tiles introduced in 3.52.2?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In the **Google Maps API 3.52.2** changelog the following added feature is listed...

*"To improve Core Web Vitals and reduce unnecessary data transfer, Maps JS now defers the loading of map tiles until the map is nearing the viewport. Maps that are created within the page's initial viewport should see no difference."*

However, this behavior seems to break things if I'm utilizing a headless command-line renderer like wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs to process the HTML/JS of a page with a map and output it to PDF, since no concept of page viewport is realized.

Is there any way to bypass or disable this behavior and restore it to pre-3.52.2 behavior for instances like these?  Or might there be any JS hackery to be done to emulate or trigger page viewport events?

Comment: I couldn't find more info on that. You may want to open an issue in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).